# Steam Post Request - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, post, steam

I'm trying to send a post request like this:

```
xhr.open("POST", "/steamapi/actions/RemoveFriendAjax", false);
    var params = "sessionID="+session_id+"&steamid="+id;
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }   
xhr.send(params);
```

I'm using an Apache Server, and this is my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ http://api.steampowered.com/$1 [P]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://steamcommunity.com/$1 [P]
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
 </IfModule>
```

Whenever I send the request I get this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) 
enter code here
```

Why is this happening? I have used GET requests with Steam and they work fine, put this POST request doesn't seem to be working.

**EDIT:** This is `steamcommunity.com's` `robot.txt` file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /actions/
Disallow: /linkfilter/
Host: steamcommunity.com
```

It says `Disallow: /actions/`, so is this the reason why I'm getting a `400` error?

Comment: Are you sure it's supposed to be `^api/$` and not `^steamapi/$` in the first rewrite rule? Are you sure you have mod_proxy loaded?

Comment: steamapi is the name of the site on my localhost server

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `setRequestHeader`?

```
xhr.open("POST", "/steamapi/actions/RemoveFriendAjax", false);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: Set up a jsFiddle and post here.

Comment: And how would I set this up?

Comment: It's just a site http://www.jsfiddle.net where you can make a public working page of your problem that people can view and try to debug the problem.

Comment: Or if you already have a public server that's hosting the site with the problem, just post a link here.

Comment: I'm using apache on my computer to host the web server.

Comment: this is the jsfiddle: its not referencing the javascript method i don't know why. http://jsfiddle.net/Varun_5/t5guw1c7/3/

Comment: Which ones are undefined my JavaScript function is defined

Comment: The Script was wrapped in onload. Now the session_id variable is missing: http://jsfiddle.net/t5guw1c7/26/